# Reading files and output is skipping lines

Tags: c++, c++11

This is homework but im stuck wondering where i went wrong. any help from you experts would be appreciated greatly!

Intended Output :

```
 Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 09:00
 Speed: 6

 Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 09:10
 Speed: 5

Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 09:20
 Speed: 5

Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 09:30
 Speed: 5

Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 09:40
 Speed: 6
```

and so on, basically in sequence

Current output

```
 Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 22:20
 Speed: 4

 Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 22:40
 Speed: 4

 Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 23:0
 Speed: 3

 Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 23:20
 Speed: 4

 Date: 31/3/2016
 Time: 23:40
 Speed: 5
```

as you can see, its skipping in 20mins interval. im not sure where in my code is causing this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Date.h"
#include "Time.h"
#include "Vector.h"

using namespace std;
typedef struct {
    Date d;
    Time t;
    float speed;
} WindLogType;

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const WindLogType& wl );
istream & operator >>( istream& input, WindLogType& wl );

int main()
{   Vector<WindLogType> windLogs;
    string day,month,year,hours,minss,strInput;
    string test;
    WindLogType windlogs2;
    ifstream infile("test2.csv");
    if(!infile) return -1;

infile >> windlogs2;
while (!infile.eof()){
//infile >> windlogs2;

getline(infile,strInput); //skip the first line
getline(infile, strInput, '/');
windlogs2.d.SetDay(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, '/');
windlogs2.d.SetMonth(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, ' ');
windlogs2.d.SetYear(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, ':');
windlogs2.t.SetHours(stod(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
windlogs2.t.SetMins(stod(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
windlogs2.speed = (stof(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');

ofstream outfile("outputFile.txt.");
outfile << windlogs2 << '\n';
cout << windlogs2 << '\n';



 }

    return 0;
    
}

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const WindLogType& wl )
{
    os << wl.d << wl.t << " Speed: " << wl.speed << '\n';

        return os;
}
istream & operator >>( istream& input, WindLogType& wl )
{
    input >> wl.d >> wl.t >> wl.speed;
    return input;
}
```

so I did some modification to

```
infile >> windlogs2;
while (!infile.eof()){
//infile >> windlogs2;

getline(infile,strInput); //skip the first line
getline(infile, strInput, '/');
windlogs2.d.SetDay(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, '/');
windlogs2.d.SetMonth(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, ' ');
windlogs2.d.SetYear(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, ':');
windlogs2.t.SetHours(stod(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
windlogs2.t.SetMins(stod(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
windlogs2.speed = (stof(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
```

where i changed the getline(input,strInput) // skip the first line to before the while loop and removed the last few getlines as such

```
infile >> windlogs2;
getline(infile,strInput); //skip the first line
while (!infile.eof()){

getline(infile,strInput); //skip the first line
getline(infile, strInput, '/');
windlogs2.d.SetDay(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, '/');
windlogs2.d.SetMonth(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, ' ');
windlogs2.d.SetYear(stoi(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput, ':');
windlogs2.t.SetHours(stod(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
windlogs2.t.SetMins(stod(strInput));
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
getline(infile,strInput,',');
windlogs2.speed = (stof(strInput));
```

and currently its not skipping the 20min interval. however the date is messed up. but if i dont change getline(input,strInput)// skip the first line, the date is all okay. anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If `getline(infile,strInput); //skip the first line` was meant to skip only the very first line of the file, then be aware that this is not what the code is doing. You have this statement in a loop, which means it eats one line on every iteration.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have tried taking that line away and when i run the codes, im always getting "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi". thats why i kept that line in there

Comment: @IgorTandetnik okay i have placed that getline(infile,strInput); outside of the while loop, it didnt give me the what() stoi error however its still having a 20mins interval.

Comment: Please show a [mre], what is the input format? I'm guessing you're reading to many times and spilling onto the next line. You should read a line into a string then parse that line in a `std::stringstream`

Comment: @AlanBirtles hi sir, the input format is a csv file. alright i will give your suggestion a shot and see if theres any difference as opposed to using stoi/stof/stod. :D